# Windows XP OS User Login Id from Javascript

Tags: javascript, windows-xp

Just wondering if there is a javascript means of getting the Windows XP login/user id logged in from within a browser application, when the user in question, say, clicks on a url within an e-mail.

Basically need to determing who has logged into the Windows XP machine.

Thanks.

Comment: most self-respecting email clients (*desktop*) do not allow javascript execution from emails.. And what you describe sounds like a humongous security vulnerability, so thankfully it is not possible..

Comment: No worries - I was just asking a question and didn't realise that me not knowing this type of info would warrant a -ve vote but nevermind. I thank you both for your responses. Pls close this thread. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unless there's a relevant IE zero day.  Obviously, this would be a huge abuse of user privacy (if you want their name, ask them!).